# Button in canvas

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток ребят!

Такой вопрос, есть канвас в нем изображение и анимация, туда же нужно закинуть и кнопки.Как будет правильнее центрировать canvas и за его пределами кнопки сделать или в самом канвасе городить кнопки.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зависит от задачи. Самостоятельные кнопки могут быть проще.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var view = new Object();
    view.start = function(){
     this.width = 1000;
     this.height = 400;
     this.color = "#e9e9e9";
     this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     this.canvas.width = this.width;
     this.canvas.height = this.height;
     document.body.prepend(this.canvas);
     this.c = this.canvas.getContext('2d'); 
     this.c.fillStyle = this.color;
     this.c.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
     
     // Create button. Вот как то так реализовывал.
     this.create_button = function(name = "Button", func = function(){alert("Button");}, x = 0, y = 0, width = 180, height = 50){
      let height_text = height * .6;
      let view_button = function(on = false){
       this.c.fillStyle = on ? "#ffc500" : "#888";
       this.c.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
       this.c.fillStyle = on ? "#000" : this.color;
       this.c.font = height_text+"pt sans-serif";
       this.c.fillText(name, x + (width - this.c.measureText(name).width) / 2 , y + (height - height_text) / 2 + height_text);
      }.bind(this);
      view_button();
      let move_button = function(e){
       view_button(e.offsetX >= x && e.offsetX < x + width && e.offsetY >= y && e.offsetY < y + height);
      }
      this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", move_button);
      let click_button = function(e){
       if(e.offsetX >= x && e.offsetX < x + width && e.offsetY >= y && e.offsetY < y + height)func();
      }
      this.canvas.addEventListener("click", click_button);
      let remove_button = function(){
       this.c.fillStyle = this.color;
       this.c.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
       this.canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", move_button);
       this.canvas.removeEventListener("click", click_button);
      }.bind(this);
      return remove_button;
     }.bind(this);
     
     let remove_button = this.create_button("test", function(){alert("test");}, 10, 150, 120, 50);
     this.create_button('remove_button "test"', remove_button, 100, 10, 900, 100);
    }
    window.onload = function(){
     view.start();
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще в любом случае тебе проще и лучше использовать стандартные html-компоненты. Нет смысла реализовывать в рамках canvas свои кнопки, это сложно, долго и скорее всего с багами. Передача событий и обмен данными делаются очень легко на обычных кнопка. Так что не заморачивайся.

P.S: имеет смысл реализовывать кнопки в canvas только если нужна нестандартная форма(отличная от прямоугольной)